# HTC Cha Cha hard reset - stored phone numbers

Tags: factory-reset, htc-chacha, hard-reset

My HTC Cha Cha won't turn on, so I want to hard reset it to factory settings. Is there a possibility of losing contacts stored on the phone? (They are very important to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between a "hard reset" (hover the mouse over that tag: *a forced reboot/shutdown by removing power (take out the battery, usually)*) and a "factory reset" (again, mouse-over: *A factory reset results in a full reset of an Android device to the original settings of the currently-installed ROM.*).

- **hard-reset:** here it's unlikely (though not absolutely impossible) to lose your stored contacts
- **factory-reset:** here it's very sure they are deleted, as all data and all user-installed apps are deleted from the device

However, you can make a backup of your contacts. In the contacts app itself, when pressing the menu key, you should find a menu item for "export/import". Select to "export", and have it save the data to your SDCard. To be absolutely safe, before doing a factory reset copy all the SDCard's contents to e.g. your PC. After the factory-reset, you can use the very same item in the contacts app to re-import the data.

Btw: contacts export uses a common file format, which is understood by many other programs as well (`*.vcf` which means VCard File). It can be read e.g. by GMail (even the Web interface) or Outlook as well.

If you have your contacts synced with Google, they should be restored automatically once you configured your Google account on the device after the factory reset.

Comment: Um I think in Android hard-rest and factory-reset are synonymous

Comment: That's like with "virus" and "malware" I guess. Some use one word for all, some distinguish. And as "malware" is not necessarily a virus, a "hard-reset" not necessarily refers to a "factory-reset" -- which is why we have two separate tags (otherwise one of them would be a synonym, and you couldn't select both for the same question ;) Hint: look at "hard-reset" as opposed to "soft-reset"; the latter is used for a clean shutdown of the device using "hardware keys" if the power menu is no longer reachable (which might happen in a force-close-loop).